# Why does grep need a dot in a regex using '$'?

Tags: regex, grep

I though I knew grep, but maybe not.

I want to find all lines in a file ending with ':'  If I run

```
grep :$ ~/greptester.txt
```

but to my surprise, it gives no results.  Sometimes I confuse '^' and '$', having to guess which is begin and which is end of line, but I checked and $ is indeed the end of a line.

After much screwing around, I accidently discovered that running

```
grep :.$ ~/greptester.txt
```

does give the expected results.  Why?

Here is the text file:

```
test line one
1 line with a colon:
ignore this line
3456 some stuff:
cat: meow; dog: bark; horse: four (4) legs.
goat, 7 elephants
```

This happens both on Ubuntu and on a Windows machine with Cygwin.

Comment: As Kent brilliantly deduced, yes, the text file was written on Windows.

Comment: Don't forget to single-quote your patterns. Better be safe than sorry when there's chance for an expansion happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file has `\r\n` (CR+LF) line endings (likely, created in windows?), whereas most UNIX files only end in `\n` (LF).

So, before grep sees the `\n` after the `:` character, there is the `\r` that it has to match with the `.` wildcard.

Comment: It's 2013 and we're still dealing with line ending nonsense.  Humans, sheesh!   Follow up question: why not make grep smart enough to ignore this detail?

Comment: You might check the version of grep you're using.  In OSX, the default is to strip the CR characters, so it behaves as you would expect (`:$` would match).  It also has the option `-U` to not strip the CR, which is how your version apparently behaves by default.

Comment: @darenw because `\r` is a real character and sometimes you may want to search for it (it's happened to me). Having `grep` arbitrarily decide that `\r` is somehow special is a BAD idea. What should it do with `\t` or any other escape character?

Comment: @terdon Unless `\r` is followed by `\n`, in which case you, _most likely_, want to ingore `\r` and treat the entire sequence `\r\n` as one character — line end.